# Interview: Find shortest path to few elements

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, shortest-path

There is a museum organized as NxN room. Some rooms are locked and inaccessible. Other rooms are open and some rooms have guards. Guards can only move north, south, east and west, only through open rooms and only within the museum. For each room, find the shortest distance to a guard. What is the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: Why should we answer this? We're not the ones applying for the job.

Comment: this is what this site is all about, helping people with answers, if u dont know the answer that's fine, me either..

Comment: Do you mean " *Visitors* can only move north, south, east, and west ..." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start, consider a relatively naive approach.

With each guard G as a vertex in the set of rooms, R=N*N, and possible paths between adjacent rooms (edges) E.

If all room minimum distances must be known, BFS from each guard to each room.

This should take time `G * (R+E)`, or something like `G*(N*N+E)`, or `G*(N*N)`.

This can certainly be optimized with memoization, as each BFS will be computing subtrees repeatedly that have already been completed. Depending on the room configuration, this could greatly reduce G from the above time complexity. I'm sure there must be something better than this, however.

Comment: +1, this is a lot better than the overkill dijkstra and especially roy-floyd solutions suggested. You can get this down to `O(N^2)` by running a queue-based BFS **after** inserting all of the guards into the queue. You don't have to rerun the BFS for each guard.

Comment: E = O(N*N), since each vertex contributes at most 4 edges. Therefore the complexity formula can be simplified to just O(G*N*N)

Answer (score 2):

Graphical solution
Each room is a node
There are edges only between rooms where the door is open
use the Floyd–Warshall algorithm and then to check the min distance between each room and each guard

number of rooms - R  = N^2

number of guards - G

the time complexity is O(R^3 +R*G)= O(R^3) = O(N^6)

R^3 for Floyd–Warshall

Comment: Actually, the number of rooms is `N^2` not `N`. I'm pretty sure this is a lot worse than `O(N^3)`.

Comment: I denoted N to be the number of rooms
I just noticed that @javasuperuser already used N, I will fix it.

Comment: No offense, but `O(N^6)` is incredibly bad, so I will keep my downvote. BFS is the right approach here.

Comment: not sure how u do it with BFS,  u need to return which guard is the closest to **each** room...

Comment: N^6 is bad if you define N as the square root of the number of rooms, which is what's going on now.  normally N is the number of vertices in the graph, which would be the number of rooms, which MrOhad lists as R.

Comment: @MrOhad - you put all the guards in a queue and then run BFS. Consider inserting a supernode with edges to all the guards in the graph. Run BFS from that supernode. Since the cost of each edge is 1, you can find the minimum distances from the guards to each room like this.

Comment: I agree with IVlad. A very simple BFS leads to O(G*N*N), so there is no need in this case for a more complex shortest distance algorithm that runs in O(N^6).

Comment: Why would the time be O(N*N*G) and not O(N*N+G), which given that the upper bound of G is N*N, would simply translate to O(N*N)?

Answer (score 2):

If we augment the museum graph with an artificial source and zero-length edges from the source to each guard, then the single-source shortest paths tree, computable via BFS (unweighted)/Dijkstra (weighted) in time **Õ(n<sup>2</sup> + g)**, gives the distance from each room to the nearest guard.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a summary of the optimal solution (**O(N^2)**), mentioned by **IVlad** and **throwawayacct**. For some reason their voice is not heard :)

Consider the NxN grid as a graph with nodes representing rooms and edges representing doors between adjacent rooms. All edges have weight 1. A set of nodes U are marked as "guarded rooms".

The idea is to use a BFS traversal, that starts from a new node connected to all guarded rooms, and scans the rooms in increasing distance order from v0. Each time a node is visited, the number of steps that have been made for reaching it represents the distance from a guarded room, and it is guaranteed to be minimal due to the path expansion order:

```
Add an artificial node v0 and connect it to all nodes in U
Create a simple queue Q, that stores pairs <node, dist>
Q.enqueue(<v0, -1>) 
Create a hash set S, that contains all visited nodes
S.add(v0)
while not Q.isEmpty() {
    pathTail := Q.dequeue()
    output distance pathTail.dist for node pathTail.node
    for all neighbours v of pathTail.node
        if not S.contains(v)
            Q.add(<v, pathTail.dist + 1>)

    S.add(pathTail.node)

}
```

**Complexity analysis**

Note that the graph is planar, so we have |V|+|E|=O(|V|). Therefore, this BFS runs in O(|V|)=O(N^2) time.

The fact that we have a uniform weight for edges makes things simple; the queue is guaranteed to have monotonous distance values. With dijkstra for example, the edges can differ in their weight so a priority queue is needed, and this affects the time complexity. The same problem presented here, with varying weights between rooms would have required O(N*N*log N) time.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like what I said last night.  The algorithm is basically a flood-fill, whose complexity depends entirely upon the area to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look at that museum as one graph and use the Dijikstra algorithm.

[wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)

You have a discussion about complexity on the given page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm implemented in this series of posts:

[Breadth and depth first search](http://www.leniel.net/2008/01/breadth-and-depth-first-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume a function edgeCost(i,j) which returns the cost of the transition from room i to room j (infinite if there is none, 1 otherwise). Also edgeCost(i,i) = 0 and there are no negative cycles. Let R be the number of rooms (R = N^2 in your case):

```
int path[R][R];
/*
 * Each path[i][j] is initialized to
 * edgeCost(i,j) or infinity if there is no 
 * edge between i and j.
 */

function play():
 for k = 1 to R:
  for i = 1 to R:
   for j = 1 to R:
    path[i][j] = min(path[i][j], path[i][k] + path[k][j]);
```

Or as you may know it, the Floyd-Warshall algorithm (all pairs shortest paths), with O(|R|^3) time complexity.

Comment: This is not `O(N^3)`, as the number of rooms is not `N`, it is `N^2`.

Comment: @IVlad: You're right, I shouldn't have used N. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a queue whose entries each hold the address of one square along with an integer.  Put the locations of all the guards in a queue, each tagged with the integer "0".  Every square should have room for a number, and they should all be initially blank.

Then, as long as there's something in the queue, pull an entry out of a queue and check whether the square in question has a marked value.  If so, just ignore that queue entry and proceed to the next one.  Otherwise, mark the square with the value from the queue and put all directly-reachable neighboring squares in the queue with a value one higher than that of the present present entry (so as each of the first batch of squares is pulled from the queue, they'll get the value "1").  Each square will only be visited once when it's blank, and each visited square will result in at most four more squares being queued, so the total number of items going through the queue will be four times the number of squares, plus the number of guards.  This value could easily be reduced by a constant factor by checking each square to see if it's blank before adding it to the queue; this would not eliminate all redundant queueing, but would eliminate some.